# Unable to bring modal popup in front of header navigation menu

Tags: jquery, css, popup, z-index, popupwindow

I have a menu header with the following css :

```
#header_bg{position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;}

#header{position: relative;width: 1024px;left: -10px;margin: 0 auto;z-index: 9999999;min-height: auto;height: auto;-webkit-transition: linear .3s;-moz-transition: linear .3s;-ms-transition: linear .3s;-o-transition: linear .3s;transition: linear .3s;}

.header_container{position: fixed;float: left;width: 100%;  z-index: 999999;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);max-height: 100%;height: auto;border-top: 1px solid #444;-webkit-transition: linear .3s;-moz-transition: linear .3s;-ms-transition: linear .3s;-o-transition: linear .3s;transition: linear .3s;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.1); box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.1);}
```

which shows the header as :

[image]

I am trying to bring a modal popup div in front of the page when the user clicks on the Log In or Sign Up button on the header. The pop up is working fine but a part of the popup is hidden below the header and it is not visible.

[image]

I tried playing with the position and z-index csss properties but no success....

Stuck with this for around 5 hours....

HTML Snapshot for Header and Popup

At first in the page the Header code comes then at the bottom is the Popup code...

**HEADER HTML CODE**

[image]

**POPUP HTML CODE**

[image]

Comment: post html too. may be the parent of the popup is behind the header and you need to give it a z-index or just keep popup out of it.

Comment: hi... edited the question with the html code screenshots.... The popup and header are in separate divs.... tried with z-index but no success... also the popup is out of the parent container...

Comment: remove the z-index from .header-container css class. you are just bringing it to front

Comment: That doesnt solve the problem as removing the z-index from the header results in vanishing the menu options :-(

Comment: You need to change the z-index for both #header and .header-container to a lower values (eg: 10) and used a z-index bigger than this for the pop-up.